# random position that knows previous position

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to make a program that puts random "N" dots in a square of size L.

How would I code it to where a random point "i" knows the previous point "i-1" and if so, try again until the two dots do not overlap?

Here is an example of what I want it to look like [random particles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKxbE.png)

Comment: Can you give us an example and you have tried so far?

Comment: i put a picture of an example on top. I haven't tried it yet but i have been researching. I think i am over thinking it since because I am looking at low discrepancy formulas but im thinking it doesnt have to be that complicated.  I am new to python so bare with me.

Comment: You could just put the random dots in a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) and check if the set already contains the new dot being added.

Comment: so like make an array and if pos[x+1,y] or pos[x,y+1] exists, retry?

Comment: That example doesn't look like "random dots"; it looks like a 10*10 array of dots with some jitter added.

Comment: the dots are random with low discrepancy. The lines are random angles. I care about the dots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example does not look like "random dots"; it looks like a 10 x 10 array of dots with some jitter added:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import random

def get_dots(width, height, pitch):
    xs, ys = [], []
    for y in range(height // pitch):
      for x in range(width // pitch):
          xs.append((x + random()) * pitch)
          ys.append((y + random()) * pitch)
    return xs, ys

def main():
    xs, ys = get_dots(20, 20, 2)
    plt.scatter(xs, ys, c="r")
    plt.axis((0., 20., 0., 20.))
    plt.show()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: thank you so much. This is the help i needed I appreciate your time and effort

Answer (score 1):

**ABSTRACT:**
When putting a new dot, look for the existence of the dot in the data-structure. If present, *recompute* the random number. Else, put the dot and increment your *counter*.

A simple data-structure that'll do the job could be a 2x2 array.

Assumptions: You've written that you do not want to overlap with the last put dot. I've assumed that you did not want any over-laps at all.

P.S.: There are better ways pick randomised elements in a list in Python.

For instance, consider the `sample` function of the `random` module. This function will allow you to get random indices from a list. This in fact would be positions where the dots would go in your case.

**EDIT**

```
import random
SQSIZE = 3
N = 5
sq = [[0 for x in range(SQSIZE)] for x in range(SQSIZE)]

randRow = random.randint(0,SQSIZE-1)
randCol = random.randint(0,SQSIZE-1)

for i in range(N):
    if sq[newrandRow][newrandCol]: # oops
        i-=1
    else:                    # yay
        sq[newrandRow][newrandCol] = 1
```

Obviously this needs some work, but the outline might help! :)

Comment: I never went over sample in my course. When my teacher showed me the example of the square grid with random particles, he talked about quasi random points. To me quasi random is the particle knowing the position of the last one to get more spaced out in the grid. I see alot of sample code in the internet and alot of people are using specific modules granted they are more complicated problems.

Comment: If quasi random is not overlapping with just the previous placement of the dot, then store the last random number in a variable in the for loop. Check against this in the if conditional.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work for you?

```
from random import random
dots_added = set()
def add_point():        
    point = frozenset([random(), random()])
    if point in dots_added:
        add_point()
    else:
        dots_added.add(point)
        ''' another code to add dots.'''
```

Comment: yeah almost like that! what do you mean by "another code to add dots"? sorry if its a stupid question

Comment: It is just a specific code to plot the dots in the module you are using. Also, If you want to set the size of the square, it is just a matter of transformations on random() such as multiply for the size and do a math.floor(). If you need assistance on plotting the dots you should post another question.